# select() returns with no incoming connection

Tags: c, sockets, select, network-programming

I'm writing a very simple server application just for the purpose of testing some code.
After creating a socket and `bind()`ing it to my localhost and some port I'd like to use `select()` to know when an incoming connection arrives to the bound socket. After that the application should print the message up to a certain lenght and then `exit()`.

My question is basically if I need to use `listen()` and `accept()` when I'm expecting only one connection (please remember this is just for testing). I believe these functions are not needed in this case and are only needed for accepting multiple incoming requests. Am I wrong?

With the above ideia in mind I wrote the following code

```
int main()
{
    int fd = TCPcreate(atoh("127.0.0.1"), 15000); /*my localhost address*/
    char *str = malloc(100);
    int a;
    fd_set rfds;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(fd,&rfds);

    a = select(fd+1,&rfds,(fd_set*)NULL,(fd_set*)NULL,(struct timeval*)NULL);

//  printf("select returns %d\nfd = %d\n", a, fd);
//  printf("fd is set? %s\n", FD_ISSET(fd,&rfds) ? "yes" : "no");

    a = TCPrecv(fd, str, 100); /*receive at most 100B */

//  printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    close(fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

TCPcreate()

```
int TCPcreate(unsigned long IP, unsigned short port)
{
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_in address;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(fd==-1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IP);
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    /* struct sockaddr_in is the same size as struct sockaddr */
    if(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address))==-1)
    {
        return -2;
    }

    return fd;
}
```

`atoh()` simply returns its argument in host byte order.

What happens when I run the program is that `select()` doesn't block waiting for a connection. Instead, it immediately returns 1. If I uncomment the `printf()`s what I get is

```
select returns 1
fd = 3
is set? yes
-1
(blank line)
```

What am I missing here?...

Comment: Listen and accept are needed for each connection.  There isn't a way to avoid using them AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the POSIX specification of [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html), the file descriptors returned are ready for reading, writing, or have an error condition on them.  This does not list 'a socket on which [`listen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/listen.html) would succeed' as one of the detectable conditions.  So, you will need to use `listen()` <s>and [`accept()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html)</s>; only after you've accepted the connection can you use `select()` on the descriptors.

As [Gonçalo Ribeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057521/goncalo-ribeiro) notes, the specification for `select()` also says:

> If the socket is currently listening, then it shall be marked as readable if an incoming connection request has been received, and a call to the `accept()` function shall complete without blocking.

That means you must have done a `listen()` on the bound socket, but you can wait on multiple sockets for incoming connections.

Comment: "If the socket is currently listening, then it shall be marked as readable if an incoming connection request has been received, and a call to the accept() function shall complete without blocking."
I suppose 'currently listening' means `listen()` must indeed be called before `select()`.

Comment: @GonçaloRibeiro In any case listen() isn't a blocking call, so there is no imaginable requirement to call select() beforehand, even if it was legal, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want blocking call - use listen().

The problem with the select is in your code is - keep the select in the loop. As it is a non-blocking call, it will only check once that someone is there to listen or not. So, you can use loop to check for listen many times.